# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor cshtml text editor format document settings

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Working with Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (beta?) I'm using Razor cshtml files however I don't like that formatting my document removes every single line of blank whitespace.

Is there any way to configure this?

I've looked under many trees in Options < Text Editor for visual studio but can't seem to find anything relevant.

**Edit**: Further thoughts, it appears that razor pages ignore the settings for Text Editor settings on lines before and after elements and chooses to always collapse them.

Comment: VS2010 SP1 came out of beta last week. Make sure you are updated to the latest version. I can't say I have seen the problem you are describing (been using Razor syntax for some time now). Have you made any changes to your text editor that would be relevant?

Comment: Are you possibly using some sort of extension that is doing this?

Comment: @JasCav didn't see that news yet so I'm sitting around waiting for the installer to do it's thing, but no I don't have something that would specifically cause that. It's also Razor only, and I've seen this behavior manifest on 2 different machines exactly the same. I'll post anything new from SP1 release. Yes, Edit < Advanced < Format Document (I remap the keys to ctrl+E+D as it's accessible 1 handed)

Comment: Alright, let us know. In the meantime, what is your process for formatting code? (I assumed Ctrl+K, Ctrl+F - but I want to make sure it's not something else.)

Comment: Same behavior for cshtml files after installing SP1 (RTW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior where format document collapses all lines apparently is triggered when you format a document with an invalid razor code segment

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Query", "Logins"))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query.Email)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Query.Email)

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

A proper razor code block as seen above wil not have it's lines removed during a format document. Only indentation might change as expected on this block.

However if there is an error in the code such as if the block was

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Query", "Logins")
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary();

    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query.Email)

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Query.Email)

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Note the missing ) at the end of the form definition, calling format on this document will result in

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Query", "Logins")
{
@Html.ValidationSummary();                
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Query.Email)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Query.Email)
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

So it looks like the moral of the story is if you ever format a razor document and see everything collapse on itself to look for a broken code segment.